# Window always returning no observations

Tags: r, zoo

I'm trying to write a simple code to understand the zoo package, but I'm always having issues with the window function. Everytime I call it, no matter if it is with my data or randomly generated data, I get the value as "without observations".

Here's the code I'm trying to use:

```
upper.bound <- as.Date(paste("01", "06", "2013", sep="-"), format="%d-%m-%Y")
lower.bound <- as.Date(paste("30", "09", "2013", sep="-"), format="%d-%m-%Y")
all_dates <- seq(as.Date(upper.bound), as.Date(lower.bound), by="day")

Z <-zoo(rnorm(200), order.by=all_dates)

x <- window(Z, upper.bound, lower.bound)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to window.zoo is `index` so what you thought was being matched to the `start`-date was not. Instead, remember to name your arguments:

```
?window.zoo
x <- window(Z, start=upper.bound, end=lower.bound)
x
#------------
  2013-06-01   2013-06-02   2013-06-03   2013-06-04   2013-06-05   2013-06-06   2013-06-07 
-0.356725268  0.165033118 -0.871486715  0.614054310  2.177144652  1.099383297  0.332047374 
  2013-06-08   2013-06-09   2013-06-10   2013-06-11   2013-06-12   2013-06-13   2013-06-14 
-1.203846835  1.996777866 -0.035678205 -0.999349827 -0.216802437 -0.620288147 -1.427030534 
  2013-06-15   2013-06-16   2013-06-17   2013-06-18   2013-06-19   2013-06-20   2013-06-21 
-0.300081002 -0.666034846 -0.662918833  0.737737776 -0.206665685 -1.183924183 -0.119519035 
  2013-06-22   2013-06-23   2013-06-24   2013-06-25   2013-06-26   2013-06-27   2013-06-28 
-0.012132861 -0.155492086  0.630016249  0.454951717  1.240600750  0.212195020  1.529695315 
  2013-06-29   2013-06-30   2013-07-01   2013-07-02   2013-07-03   2013-07-04   2013-07-05 
-0.791875017 -0.002926672  0.333920298  0.272069968 -0.152630683  0.324500744 -0.004795280 
  2013-07-06   2013-07-07   2013-07-08   2013-07-09   2013-07-10   2013-07-11   2013-07-12 
 0.879553367 -0.212456832  1.990937136 -0.389366651  0.763931167  1.860765480  0.015482952 
  2013-07-13   2013-07-14   2013-07-15   2013-07-16   2013-07-17   2013-07-18   2013-07-19 
snipped output
```